# How to concatenate strings and commas in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, coalesce

I'm relatively new to MSSQL, so sorry if the question might sounds trivial. I want to concatenate multiple fields with a delimiter `,`. However, when the field is empty, the extra `,` will be included in the result string as well. So is there an easy way to solve this problem? For example,

```
SELECT VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier + ',' + 
       VRI.Street_Direction + ',' + 
       VRI.Street_Name + ',' + 
       VRI.Street_Direction + ',' + 
       VRI.Street_Suffix + ',' + 
       VRI.Street_Post_Direction + ',' + 
       VRI.Unit
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the columns are empty instead of null, you can try this:

```
SELECT VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier 
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
       + VRI.Street_Direction
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Street_Direction <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
       + VRI.Street_Name
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Street_Name <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
       + VRI.Street_Direction
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Street_Direction <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
       + VRI.Street_Suffix
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Street_Suffix <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
       + VRI.Street_Post_Direction
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Street_Post_Direction <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
       + VRI.Unit
    + CASE WHEN VRI.Unit<> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I got syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near '.'` Any idea?

Comment: @Chan - Looking into what it might be. Also, I made a bunch of other mistakes that i'll fix really fast.

Comment: Now, it worked perfectly. Thanks for such an elegant solution ;).

Comment: @Chan - Just keep in mind that this only works if the fields are empty strings. If their values could be null, you'll definitely want to look into combining this with some of the other solutions.

Answer (score 13):

This modified version of Lamak's handles NULL or strings containing only space/empty:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier, '') + ',', '') + 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Street_Direction, '') + ',', '') + 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Street_Name, '') + ',', '') + 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Street_Direction, '') + ',', '') + 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Street_Suffix, '') + ',', '') + 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Street_Post_Direction, '') + ',', '') + 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(VRI.Unit, ''), '')
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Comment: This example doesn't work. COALESCE function requires at least 2 parameters.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get it to work with a slightly different approach.  Putting the commas at the beginning of each field and then removing the first one with the STUFF function worked for me:

```
SELECT 

    STUFF((COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier, ''), '') +
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Street_Direction, ''), '') + 
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Street_Name, ''), '')) +
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Street_Direction, ''), '')) +
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Street_Suffix, ''), '')) +
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Street_Post_Direction, ''), '')) +
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(VRI.Unit, ''), ''))
    , 1, 2, '')

FROM View_Report_Information_Tables AS VRI
```

Comment: The brackets are a bit all-over-the-place, but this works well!

Answer (score 4):

For **SQL 2008+**

Using
    ISNULL(Colmn1 + ', ', '')
Will always result with a leading comma in the end, so you'll have to handle it.
Example:

```
DECLARE @Column1 NVARCHAR(10) = 'Column1'
,   @Column2 NVARCHAR(10) = 'Column2'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(  ISNULL(@Column1 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@Column2 + ', ', '')
            , 0 --Starting from 0 not 1 to remove leading comma
            , LEN(ISNULL(@Column1 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@Column2 + ', ', '')))
```

Or we could approach this the other way around and use the STUFF function to remove our beginning comma which looks cleaner, example:

```
SELECT  STUFF   (ISNULL(( ', ' + @Column1), '') + ISNULL(( ', ' + @Column2), ''), 1, 2, N'')
```

For **SQL 2012+** we could use the CONCAT function and remove beginning comma using STUFF similar to our previous example but avoiding ISNULL:

```
SELECT  STUFF(CONCAT( ', ' + @Column1, ', ' + @Column2), 1, 2, N'')
```

For **SQL 2017+** CONCAT_WS was introduced where you can concatinate/join multiple string columns with a delimiter specified in the first argument of the function:

[MS Documents CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

MS Doc Example:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',' --delimiter
            ,'1 Microsoft Way', NULL, NULL, 'Redmond', 'WA', 98052) AS Address;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier + ',','') + 
        COALESCE(VRI.Street_Direction + ',','') + 
        COALESCE(VRI.Street_Name + ',','') + 
        COALESCE(VRI.Street_Direction + ',','') + 
        COALESCE(VRI.Street_Suffix + ',','') + 
        COALESCE(VRI.Street_Post_Direction + ',','') + 
        COALESCE(VRI.Unit,'')
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Comment: @Lamak: Many thanks, very clean and easy to understand. But the commas are still there :(. Any idea?

Comment: @Chan: What do you mean with "the commas are still there"?, can you show an example of the input and the output?. The query above should work that when one field is `NULL`, you shouldn't get any extra commas.

Comment: @Lamak: This is the result that I got: `,,Mae Rose,,Dr,,`

Comment: @Chan: I believe that your problem is that you are not getting `NULL` when the field is empty, you are getting a ''.

Comment: @Lamak: So how can I deal with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Quandary: I'm running SQL Server 2008 R.

Answer (score 2):

Short or long answer?

Short answer - dont. This is a formatting issue, not a database issue.

Long answer - When you concatenate a string and a null in sql server, the result is null. So you can use combinations of ISNULL

```
SELECT ISNULL(afield + ',','') + ISNULL(bfield + ',','')
```

Comment: Will never be null because you have added a comma to null.

Comment: @freegnu - SQL Server from 2008 calls a null + a string a null.

Comment: I tried this for MSSQL 2008 and it worked as I wanted. I wanted to concat lastname + firstname + initial. In this I wanted to insert a comma ', ' after lastname only if it is not null. Thanks for the info Jamlec

Answer (score 1):

You have to use select case when IsNull(fieldname, '')= '' or ltrim(rtrim(fieldname))='') Then ... Else...  end +...

**Edit:**
Was written from Android mobile.
Below your example.
The following translations (from German) apply, FYI:

> Vorname:  given name  
>   Name:     surname 
>   Benutzer: User

And here's the example code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_RPT_SEL_Benutzer]  
AS  
SELECT 

    BE_ID AS RPT_UID, 

    CASE 
        WHEN (ISNULL(BE_Name, '0') = '0' OR LTRIM(RTRIM(BE_Name)) = '')  AND (ISNULL(BE_Vorname, '0') = '0' OR LTRIM(RTRIM(BE_Vorname)) = '')
            THEN ''
        WHEN (ISNULL(BE_Name, '0') = '0' OR LTRIM(RTRIM(BE_Name)) = '')
            THEN ISNULL(BE_Vorname, '') 
        WHEN (ISNULL(BE_Vorname, '0') = '0' OR LTRIM(RTRIM(BE_Vorname)) = '')
            THEN ISNULL(BE_Name, '') 
        ELSE
            ISNULL(BE_Name, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(BE_Vorname, '') 
    END AS RPT_Name, 

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BE_Name, BE_Vorname ASC) AS RPT_Sort 

FROM T_Benutzer
```

Comment: Can you give me one example? Thanks.

Comment: @Chan: Example added. @Cade Roux: Is this still true for SQL 2008? I remember needing it... Well ISNULL(BE_Name, '') = '' should suffice then, so forget all the or statements, but only the or, not the and.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ISNULL(field + ',', '')`

Comment: Thanks, however the commas are still there :(. Any idea?

Comment: Will never be null because you have added a comma to null.

Comment: @freegnu try this select isnull(null + ',','').  Null + 'a string' returns null

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT isnull(VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier + ',','')+
   isnull(VRI.Street_Direction + ',','')+
   isnull(VRI.Street_Name + ',','')+
   isnull(VRI.Street_Direction + ',','')+
   isnull(VRI.Street_Suffix + ',','')+
   isnull(VRI.Street_Post_Direction + ',','')+
   isnull(VRI.Unit,'')
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because the comma also needs to be removed when string2 = null

Comment: The fields can also be string.empty or only whitespaces. Additionally, this only works on ms-sql 2008 where string + null =null, unlike sql 2005.

Comment: @Quandary string + null = null on SQL Server 2005 if you have ANSI_NULLs ON (which it should be by default, even on SQL Server 2005).

Answer (score 0):

I would agree completely with Jamiec's short answer.

Otherwise, I would look at a nasty solution of using a REPLACE([concat], ',,', ',') everywhere you concatenate two columns, and then figure out how to trim commas from the beginning and end of the string where the first and last columns might be empty.  Very very messy.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to see if I can get it without using  CASE but could not.  A long-winded way of mine:

```
    SELECT case when isnull(nullif(VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier, ''),'')='' then '' else VRI.Street_Number_and_Modifier end
+ case when isnull(nullif(VRI.Street_Direction, ''),'')='' then '' else ',' + VRI.Street_Direction end
+ case when isnull(nullif(VRI.Street_Name, ''),'')='' then '' else ',' + VRI.Street_Name end
+ case when isnull(nullif(VRI.Street_Suffix, ''),'')='' then '' else ',' + VRI.Street_Suffix end
+ case when isnull(nullif(VRI.Street_Post_Direction, ''),'')='' then '' else ',' + VRI.Street_Post_Direction end
+ case when isnull(nullif(VRI.Street_Post_Direction, ''),'')='' then '' else ',' + VRI.Street_Post_Direction end
FROM View_Report_Information_Tables VRI
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_ADDRSS_LN_1_TXT, ''), ',')+
    COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_ADDRSS_LN_2_TXT, '') , ',')+
    COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_ADDRSS_LN_3_TXT, '') , ',')+
    COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_CITY_TXT, '') , ',')+
    COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_ST_TXT, '') , ',')+
    COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_CNTRY_TXT, '') , ',')+
    COALESCE(NULLIF(ad.UDEFPROPERTYADDRESS_PSTL_CD, '') , '')
    FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS ad
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not add any commas if null-strings

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', IFNULL(column1, NULL), 
         IFNULL(column2, NULL), IFNULL(column3, NULL), 
         IFNULL(column4, NULL), IFNULL(column5, NULL))
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Downvote, sqlserver does not have the function CONCAT_WS. That is a MYSQL function.